# Book about princess who travels to another planet to wed the prince who then is exiled

Tags: story-identification, novel, audio-book

I can't remember the name of this novel. Non-traditional princess is sent across space by her father the king to marry the crown prince as a diplomatic move. There are priests and a type of angelic presences.  The princess set up sword-fighting lessons for the ladies of the court and scandalized everyone. The prince gets a disease that causes him to be exiled to a walled city where the diseased are sent to die.  There are factions among the exiled.  Princess eventually goes to the city. I think the prince was hiding his identity.  Eventually, there was a battle against the king's soldiers.

This was probably published 3 to 5 years ago.  I listened to the audio-book.  It seemed like it may have been the first of a series but I'm not positive.  My library had it classified as science fiction but it had a lot of fantasy elements.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site. As this is a story identification question, you can also have a look at this [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the plot points sound like the book [Elantris](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?168009) by Brandon Sanderson, [Wikipedia article here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elantris), though there are also some mismatches.

The princess Sarene is engaged to prince Raoden and travels to wed him, but the story is set on a single world not in space and Sarene travels by boat (for five days). When she arrives she learns that Raoden has contracted a *disease* (it's not really a disease) and has been exiled to the walled city of Elantris.

Sarene does arrange fencing lessons for the ladies of the court. She was taught to fence as a child and enjoys it.

Sarene does make her way into the walled city, Elantris, and finds Raoden. They finally wed, and Raoden becomes King.

Lastly the book was published in 2005 so it is outside your probable time frame.

Comment: I think it must have been Elantris.  Thanks so much for your assistance!